# "scope" attribute ignored in TWA

Tags: trusted-web-activity

I have a "scoped" **PWA** application with a **manifest.json** file like:

```
{
...
"start_url": "/my-pwa/",
"scope": "/my-pwa/",
"display":"standalone"
...
}
```

When installed as **PWA**, it works as expected:

- It opens all urls from scope inside the PWA window (eg: **/my-pwa**/sub-path1, **/my-pwa/**..., etc)
- It opens non scoped urls in diferent browser window (eg: **/other-path**, **/other-path2/**..., etc)

When installed as **TWA** (created using **bubblewrap**, with the corresponding assetlinks.json), the problem appears:

- It opens **all urls from the domain** inside the **TWA** window, even the **non scoped** urls (eg: **/other-path**) that should be opened in diferent window, like urls from other domains.

Is this a bug or is this the expected behavior? Do you know any workaround to force non scoped urls to open in diferent window?